How to call Org Babel function from an Org Table
So, I have this function defined in an org mode file:
#+name: index
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var s="" n=1
(let ((str (upcase (s-replace-regexp "[^A-Za-z]" "" s))))
  (substring str (1- n) n))
#+end_src

I have a simple table:
| Word | Number | Letter |
|------+--------+--------|
| Foo  |      1 |        |
| Bar  |      2 |        |
| Baz  |      1 |        |
| Quux |      3 |        |

I want to set each cell in the column "Letter" to the result of calling "index" with the corresponding Word and Letter values.
I tried the following, but it didn't work. It just gave me "#ERROR" in the 3rd column:
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-sbe index (s $1) (n $2))

Try C-c { to turn on formula debugging. Hint: $2 is a string, not an integer.

org-sbe is a strange beast: in addition to the string-to-number conversion in the source block, I also had to change the org-sbe call arguments to $$1 and $$2 - see the doc string of org-sbe. But I don't remember having to do that in the past: maybe something changed recently, maybe I just misremember.

Here's the version that worked for me (Org mode version 9.8-pre (release_9.7.9-119-g86abaf)):
#+name: index
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var s="bar" n="3"
    (let ((str (upcase (s-replace-regexp "[^A-Za-z]" "" s)))
          (m (string-to-number n)))
    (substring str (1- m) m)))
#+end_src

| Word | Number | Letter |
|------+--------+--------|
| Foo  |      1 | F      |
| Bar  |      2 | A      |
| Baz  |      1 | B      |
| Quux |      3 | U      |
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-sbe "index" (s $$1) (n $$2))

